# WebStorm and ES6 classes with getters, defined inside a function

Tags: class, webstorm, anonymous-function, getter, ecmascript-6

Trying to use ES6 classes in WebStorm 8/9 and getting this error when I add a getter:

[image]

```
'use strict';

(function () {
  class Collection {
    constructor(resource) {
      this._models = [];
      this._resource = resource;
    }

    fetch() {
      this._models = this._resource.query();
    }

    get models() {
      return this._models;
    }
  }
})();
```

Moving the class definition outside the anonymous function removes the error, but this isn't an option.

I disabled all inspections and intentions in the preferences. Any ideas how to remove/suppress this message?

Comment: This code is syntactically perfectly valid, report it as a bug. Although it doesn't make much sense to define a local class without ever using it?

Comment: Definitely no sense in that, it's just an example snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WEB-13447](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13447) is fixed in webStorm 10. Please try [WebStorm 10 RC](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP)